# text from popen() is cut of prematurely when console in UTF-8 mode

Tags: c++, windows, console, popen

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>


using namespace std;
int main() {
  SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
  wstringstream wss;
  wchar_t buff[256];
  FILE *in;
  if(!(in = _wpopen(L"dir %windir%", L"r"))) { return 1; }
  while(!feof(in)) {
    if (fgetws(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
      wss << buff;
    }
  }
  pclose(in);
  wstring wstr;
  wstr = wss.str();
  wcout << wstr.c_str();
}
```

and the effect looks likethis:

```
[...]

2011-04-10  14:11    <DIR>          .
2011-04-10  14:11    <DIR>          ..
2011-04-10  14:11    <DIR>          system32
2011-04-10  14:11    <DIR>          system
2011-04-10  14:11    <DIR>          repair
2011-04-10  14:11    <DIR>          Help
2011-04-10  14:11    <DIR>          Config
2011-04-10  14:11    <DIR>          Cursors
2011-04-10  14:11    <DIR>          Media
2011-04-10  14:11    <DIR>          java
2011-04-10  14:11    <DIR>          Web
2011-04-10  14:11    <DIR>          addins
2012-06-09  11:29             2
```

Seems that end of file character is passed somehow in the string or what... I have no idea.
But if I change encoding back to one-byte all works ok..

Maybe I forgot to change some function here to its multi-byte alternative ?

Comment: What happens if you open the file in binary mode? I know Windows does some strange things in text mode, e.g. if a file contains 0x1A then reading the file in text mode will act as though the 0x1A byte marks the end of the file.

Comment: I found that the text is cut of at space that is between thousands and hundreds in file size, so that `2` at the end is that the file about to be print has about 2kB, and the sequence that causes issue here is: `0xC2 0xA0`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37768701/1639256