# Difference between text streams opened via _popen and fopen

Tags: c++, c, windows, popen, msvcrt

I'm seeing a curious aberration in a Windows text stream opened via `_popen`, which I don't see in an equivalent text stream opened with `fopen`. I'm not exactly sure what's going on, but it seems to happen when a newline (`\r\n`) appears at or near the boundary between consecutive calls to `fread`, and it leads to a newline being completely lost. Here is a minimal test case which identifies a difference between text streams opened with `_popen` and `fopen`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // input.txt: https://gist.github.com/oktal3700/c3112246373097b5eee050c095246c28
    // GitHub Gist will supply the file with Unix line-endings, so you will need to
    // convert it to Windows line-endings before running the test.
    FILE *file =  fopen(     "C:\\Users\\Mat\\Desktop\\test\\input.txt", "r");
    FILE *proc = _popen("type C:\\Users\\Mat\\Desktop\\test\\input.txt", "r");
    if (! file || ! proc) return 1;
    char buf1[256];
    char buf2[256];
    bool done = false;
    while (! feof(file) && ! feof(proc)) {
        int count1 = fread(buf1, 1, 255, file);
        int count2 = fread(buf2, 1, 255, proc);
        if (! done && 0 != memcmp(buf1, buf2, std::min(count1, count2))) {
            done = true;
            std::cout << std::string(buf1, count1) << "\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < count1; ++i) std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << int(buf1[i]) << " ";
            std::cout << "\n\n";
            std::cout << std::string(buf2, count2) << "\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < count2; ++i) std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << int(buf2[i]) << " ";
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the input file: [`input.txt`](https://gist.github.com/oktal3700/c3112246373097b5eee050c095246c28)

As the comment says, the gist is supplied with Unix line-endings, so you would need to convert it to Windows line-endings before running the test.

The output looks like this:

```
png
C:/Users/Mat/Projects/swift/src/blackmisc/icons/diagona/icons/table-insert-column.png
C:/Users/Mat/Projects/swift/src/blackmisc/icons/diagona/icons/question-button.png
C:/Users/Mat/Projects/swift/src/blackmisc/icons/diagona/icons/arrow-270-medium.png

70 6e 67 0a 43 3a 2f 55 73 65 72 73 2f 4d 61 74 2f 50 72 6f 6a 65 63 74 73 2f 73 77 69 66 74 2f
73 72 63 2f 62 6c 61 63 6b 6d 69 73 63 2f 69 63 6f 6e 73 2f 64 69 61 67 6f 6e 61 2f 69 63 6f 6e
73 2f 74 61 62 6c 65 2d 69 6e 73 65 72 74 2d 63 6f 6c 75 6d 6e 2e 70 6e 67 0a 43 3a 2f 55 73 65
72 73 2f 4d 61 74 2f 50 72 6f 6a 65 63 74 73 2f 73 77 69 66 74 2f 73 72 63 2f 62 6c 61 63 6b 6d
69 73 63 2f 69 63 6f 6e 73 2f 64 69 61 67 6f 6e 61 2f 69 63 6f 6e 73 2f 71 75 65 73 74 69 6f 6e
2d 62 75 74 74 6f 6e 2e 70 6e 67 0a 43 3a 2f 55 73 65 72 73 2f 4d 61 74 2f 50 72 6f 6a 65 63 74
73 2f 73 77 69 66 74 2f 73 72 63 2f 62 6c 61 63 6b 6d 69 73 63 2f 69 63 6f 6e 73 2f 64 69 61 67
6f 6e 61 2f 69 63 6f 6e 73 2f 61 72 72 6f 77 2d 32 37 30 2d 6d 65 64 69 75 6d 2e 70 6e 67 0a 

png
C:/Users/Mat/Projects/swift/src/blackmisc/icons/diagona/icons/table-insert-column.png
C:/Users/Mat/Projects/swift/src/blackmisc/icons/diagona/icons/question-button.pngC:/Users/Mat/Projects/swift/src/blackmisc/icons/diagona/icons/arrow-270-medium.png
C
70 6e 67 0a 43 3a 2f 55 73 65 72 73 2f 4d 61 74 2f 50 72 6f 6a 65 63 74 73 2f 73 77 69 66 74 2f
73 72 63 2f 62 6c 61 63 6b 6d 69 73 63 2f 69 63 6f 6e 73 2f 64 69 61 67 6f 6e 61 2f 69 63 6f 6e
73 2f 74 61 62 6c 65 2d 69 6e 73 65 72 74 2d 63 6f 6c 75 6d 6e 2e 70 6e 67 0a 43 3a 2f 55 73 65
72 73 2f 4d 61 74 2f 50 72 6f 6a 65 63 74 73 2f 73 77 69 66 74 2f 73 72 63 2f 62 6c 61 63 6b 6d
69 73 63 2f 69 63 6f 6e 73 2f 64 69 61 67 6f 6e 61 2f 69 63 6f 6e 73 2f 71 75 65 73 74 69 6f 6e
2d 62 75 74 74 6f 6e 2e 70 6e 67 43 3a 2f 55 73 65 72 73 2f 4d 61 74 2f 50 72 6f 6a 65 63 74 73
2f 73 77 69 66 74 2f 73 72 63 2f 62 6c 61 63 6b 6d 69 73 63 2f 69 63 6f 6e 73 2f 64 69 61 67 6f
6e 61 2f 69 63 6f 6e 73 2f 61 72 72 6f 77 2d 32 37 30 2d 6d 65 64 69 75 6d 2e 70 6e 67 0a 43
```

Can this be explained by some quirk of `_popen` that I don't know about?

I know that I can work around it by opening the stream in binary mode. I am asking to know the cause of the difference between `_popen` and `fopen`.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote and for removing the [tag:c] tag. I've restored it because the question is about a C function.

Comment: As per the duplicate, [this is a known issue.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1902345/regression-fread-on-a-pipe-drops-some-newlines)